# Obtaining a number from another by a function composition sequence

Tags: functions, linear-transformations

Problem: Given two natural numbers $x,y$ and two bijective linear functions $f,g$ on the same domain $\mathbb{N}$.
Is there an arbitraty sequence of those composed functions, such that $y$ can be obtained from $x$?

Example: $f(x)=2x$, $g(x)=x+3$.  Let $x=2, y =11$. Then $g\circ f\circ f (2)$ would  be a answer. If you choose $y=12$ instead there is no answer.

Has this problem any specific name? Are there proof techniqes to show that there exists such a sequence or not (not necessary to give the concrete sequence)?

What if addtionaly $f$ and $g$ are commutative?

Comment: Suppose $f$ and $g$ are increasing functions and $f(x_0) > x_0$ and $g(x_0) > x_0$ then any composition of $f,g$ will be greater than $x_0$ now choose $x \ge x_0$ and  $y < x_0$

Comment: @DougM How would this do the job? We cannot change $x$ and $y$, both are given and fixed.

Comment: It shows that that it cannot necessarily be done. $f(x) = 2x, g(x) = 4x$   Let $x = 1$, let $y = 1$  In this case, there is another problem, in that 1 is not in the image of either function.